# How to add the first value of a column in SQL over another grouping variable

Tags: sql, inner-join, teradata, self-join

I have a database with a table of the following kind:

| customer_id | customer_type | customer_state | state_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | A | 1 | 2020-01-05 |
| 1 | B | 2 | 2020-01-06 |
| 2 | X | 0 | 2019-02-07 |
| 2 | Y | 0 | 2019-02-07 |
| 2 | X | 0 | 2019-02-07 |

The columns customer state and state_date represent the evolution over time of the current state of the customer, while `customer_id` is clearly an unique identifier for the customer.

I am interested in obtaining a table (using an SQL query) with an additional column `first_type` that tells for each customer the first state it had, like in this example:

| customer_id | customer_type | customer_state | state_date | first_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 2020-01-01 | A |
| 1 | A | 1 | 2020-01-05 | A |
| 1 | B | 2 | 2020-01-06 | A |
| 2 | X | 0 | 2019-02-07 | X |
| 2 | Y | 0 | 2019-02-07 | X |
| 2 | X | 0 | 2019-02-07 | X |

Is it possible to do it in SQL? I've tried with a self-join, but it's complicated for me to understand how to pick the first row, or generally the `n-th` row, over each customer.

Specifically, I'm using Teradata SQL, if some specific functions can be used for this task.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server, or as you're closing statement says, Teradata? Someone with 7K+ rep should know how to tag correctly.

Comment: Started a week ago using databases, indeed. My database is Teradata, yes. As far as In understand though it's a SQL dialect, so standard SQL commands should work, right?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (technically, multi-sets).  There is no way to distinguish the last three rows based on the information you have provided.  There is no "first".

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY state_date) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT customer_id, customer_type, customer_state, state_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN customer_type END) OVER
           (PARTITION BY customer_id) first_type
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a function in Teradata/Standard SQL:

```
SELECT 
   t.*
  ,FIRST_VALUE(customer_type)
   OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
         ORDER BY state_date) AS first_type
FROM mytable AS t
```